# How to get the Year value from models.DateField...?

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-models

I want to calculate age. I tried below code...

```
DOB = models.DateField()
Age = models.IntegerField(max_length= 2, default= date.today().year - DOB.year)
```

I got Error

```
AttributeError: 'DateField' object has no attribute 'year'
```

How can I get the Year value from DateField..

Answer (score 3):

You can't set a dynamic default like this, nor should you really need to store it in a database

Just make it a property (maybe even `cached_property`)

```
@property
def age(self):
   return date.today().year - self.DOB.year
```

Comment: ValueError: Cannot serialize: <property object at 0x0000000004A16EF8>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.

Comment: DOB = m.DateField()
    @property
    def age(self):
        return date.today().year - self.DOB.year
    Age = m.IntegerField(default=age)

Comment: @python19 - "You can't set a dynamic default like this, nor should you really need to store it in a database"

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py:

```
import datetime
from .models import *

def age(self):
    return datetime.date.today().year - self.DOB.year
```

You can use that returned value to display into an HTML file or store into the database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..  But I'm getting "" import Error  """ while doing it..... the reason is first i need to import the ~age~ method at beginning  of models.py.. That time it will give import error... because models.py not yet defined any models